# SQL error with nested SELECT

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

The error is 'Operation must use an updatable query'.

I am trying to update the 'orders' table with the information below, however only the price of 1 item will be provided through a text box and I am trying to calculate the total order value using the quantity ordered, which will already be in this table.

The code below includes the data taken from the variables. With the 2 in 'VAT = 2' and 'price = 2' being the price of one single unit (£2.00). The total order value will be stored within the 'price' field and the VAT should be calculated using the same code, but times by 0.2 to give the 20% VAT.

```
UPDATE orders 
   SET Invoice_number = 'IN9999', 
       delivery_note_number = 'DN6000', 
       price =2 *
        (SELECT quantity 
           FROM orders 
          WHERE purchase_order_number = 'PO7512'
        ), 
       VAT = (2 * 
         (SELECT quantity 
            FROM orders 
           WHERE purchase_order_number = 'PO7512'
         )/100) * 20, 
       shipping = 3 
WHERE purchase_order_number = 'PO7512'
```

Maybe I can't use nested query's this way. I'm not sure, but any help would be appreciated :) Thanks!

Comment: This does not have anything to do with your subqueries.  It probably has to do with `[orders]` not being a table, or at least not an update-able one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of subquerying, you can access the whole record directly in the update, like so:

```
UPDATE Orders 
   SET Invoice_number = 'IN9999', 
       Delivery_note_number = 'DN6000', 
       Price = 2 * quantity, 
       VAT = (40 * quantity)/100, 
       Shipping = 3 
 WHERE purchase_order_number = 'PO7512'
```

Note that with fractions it's always better to multiply first and divide later.

Comment: Your query doesn't specify where `quantity` is coming from.

Comment: Oh, so I can still use the value of quantity even though it isn't selected at all within the query? I just tried that code, but still got the same error.

Comment: @darkjoe31 the code should work, what's the definition of the table?

Comment: @Sklivvz Ah, I didn't see that, I was perceptually blind :(